# How to define board parameters when compiling Arduino code via command line

Tags: command-line, arduino, arduino-ide

I need to upload my codes using Arduino IDE via command line. I'm basing my studies on this manual: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/build/shared/manpage.adoc

From it, I know that I need to define the architecture (most cases avr) and the board name. In some cases, I also need to define the cpu. For example, when using mega and nano boards:

```
arduino --board arduino:avr:nano:cpu=atmega168
```

The manual defines the --board option as:

```
--board package:arch:board[:parameters]
```

where `:parameters` "is a comma-separated list of boards specific parameters that are normally shown under submenus of the "Tools" menu".

I need to know what are the other available parameters and if there is some board that needs more information.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that "there's no way to list the possible parameters because anyone who makes a board definition can add any parameters they like. There is no standardization imposed on the parameters."

More info: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/8716